# Is there a relationship between 2D airfoil aerodynamic results and a revolution body from that airfoil?

Tags: aerodynamics, airfoil

The airfoil would be symmetric and the axis of revolution would be its chord line.

Edit1: To clarify the question, suppose we have a NACA 0010. Then, using for example XFoil, I'm able to get, for example, Cd(AoA). Now, I take the airfoil, and I create a body of revolution, with the axis of revolution being the chord line of the airfoil, with the resulting body being like a teardrop. I want to know if there is a way to correlate my 2D Cd(AoA) to the 3D Cd(AoA) of the body I created, so I can predict some of its aerodynamics (with some degree of accuracy) without having to run 3D CFD analysis on it.

Comment: Welcome to Av.SE. Is this a homework question, by chance?  What sort of "relationship" are you looking for?

Comment: @RalphJ Thank you. It's a question regarding my thesis. I was looking for a relationship for example, from 2D drag coefficient to 3D drag coefficient on the body of revolution

Comment: I find the question perfectly clear. At least the thickness of the airfoil will show up in the body of revolution, increasing its aspect ratio and the suction on the surface. Sorry that I cannot give a better answer - a comment leaves preciously little space for a complete answer.

Comment: Thank you @PeterKämpf. I'll edit the question so I can clarify it anyway.